# Elementary matrix inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be a positive semidefinite matrix. Is the mapping
$$
\begin{align}
F \ \colon \ \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} &\to \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} \\
X &\mapsto X^{-1} - (X+A)^{-1} \\
\end{align}
$$
monotonically non-increasing over the positive definite matrices? Specifically, do we have the implication
$$
0 \prec X_1 \preceq X_2 \quad \Rightarrow \quad F(X_1) - F(X_2) \succeq 0
$$
where the notation $U \preceq V$ (resp. $U \prec V$) means that $V-U$ is positive semidefinite (resp. positive definite)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no. Suppose
$$
X = I,\ Y=\pmatrix{2&1\\ 1&2},\ A = \pmatrix{0&0\\ 0&1}.
$$
Then $Y\succeq X\succ0$ but one can verify that
$$
F(X)-F(Y) = \frac1{30}\pmatrix{-2&4\\ 4&7}\not\succeq0.
$$
By continuity, when $\varepsilon>0$ is small, we also have $Y+\varepsilon I\succ X\succ0$ but $F(X)-F(Y+\varepsilon I)$ is indefinite. Replace $A$ by $A+\varepsilon I$, we obtain a counterexample with a positive definite $A$ as well.

Comment: Thanks for your counterexample. Then I suppose the monotonicity holds at least for the trace of $F$?

Comment: @jens Yes, the trace of $F$ is monotonic.

Comment: Good to know! However when I try to prove the monotonicity of the trace, I am still stuck. By differentiation I get that the question is equivalent to proving that $\operatorname{tr}\bigl[W\bigl((X+A)^{-2}-X^{-2}\bigr)\bigr]$ is non-positive for any positive semidefinite $W$. And if I'm not mistaken, that's equivalent to $(X+A)^{-2}-X^{-2}$ being negative semidefinite. So I'm back at square one.

Comment: @jens Sorry, I was wrong. The trace of $F$ is not monotonic decreasing. For a counterexample, consider $X^{-1}=\pmatrix{4&-2\\ -2&12}$ and $(X+A)^{-1}=\pmatrix{3&-4\\ -4&6}$. We have $(X+A)^{-2}-X^2=\pmatrix{5&-4\\ -4&-96}$, so that the trace of $F$ is strictly increasing in the direction of $W=\operatorname{diag}(1,0)$ and it is strictly decreasing in the direction of $W=\operatorname{diag}(0,1)$.

Comment: Thanks again for this second counterexample. I find this very intriguing. Can you think of any matrix-to-scalar operation (e.g., matrix norm) other than the trace, for which this monotonicity might hold? My $A$ is some sort of small $\epsilon$-quantity, and all I want to do is to upper-bound the modulus of that trace difference properly. There must be a simple way.